# How to allow active components in IE using code

Tags: html, internet-explorer

We have to link a video in our website and i found out IE6 only supports .swf format videos. But IE prompting for allowing active component every time i open the web page. I found out there is a security option in tools->advanced->security. But is there anyway to do this using html code? Or is there any other way to post video in website that IE6 can support??
Here is our html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Click the Link to Play the Object</h2>
<a href="file:///D:\desktop\BS Demo.swf">Play a video file</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't include "Thank you" in your question. It is useless noise.

Answer (score 0):

This is a user-controlled setting that is *deliberately* hidden from developers, such that the user (or administrator) can prevent active components from executing no matter what web authors want for their content. There's no way to control this from the code, I'm afraid!

There are other video formats: Windows Media format (.wmv) is available on Windows by default, but there's also QuickTime, SilverLight… and a whole host of less popular formats. But these are all active components, and as such will all be subjected to the same user opt-in, dependeing on how the user's machine is configured.